# Why is php artisan migrate resulting " Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused "

Tags: php, laravel-8, wsl-2, artisan-migrate

I was trying to set up a Laravel project but whenever I hit **php artisan migrate** it results in this error

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = src and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕ 

      +36 vendor frames 
  37  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I am using laravel/framework:^8.12 in WSL Ubuntu 20.04LTS.I know this is a really common problem ,but none of the solution worked for me .

my .env file

> APP_NAME=Laravel APP_ENV=local APP_KEY= APP_DEBUG=true
> APP_URL=http://localhost
>
> LOG_CHANNEL=stack LOG_LEVEL=debug
>
> DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=src
> DB_USERNAME=root DB_PASSWORD=
>
> BROADCAST_DRIVER=log CACHE_DRIVER=file QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
> SESSION_DRIVER=file SESSION_LIFETIME=120
>
> MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1
>
> REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 REDIS_PASSWORD=null REDIS_PORT=6379
>
> MAIL_MAILER=smtp MAIL_HOST=mailhog MAIL_PORT=1025 MAIL_USERNAME=null
> MAIL_PASSWORD=null MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
> MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
>
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
> AWS_BUCKET=
>
> PUSHER_APP_ID= PUSHER_APP_KEY= PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
> PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
>
> MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
> MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

Comment: can you access the database with those connection details outside of Laravel? Using `mysql-client` or a GUI application like TablePlus, dbeaver etc..

Comment: If you have MySQL installed on WSL. Open a terminal window and run the following: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` (type password in when prompted)

Comment: @Galironfydar I have installed TablePlus Can you provide me a link or explain how to connect both these two,individual steps would be great,I have never done anything like this before.Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Galironfydar that results in ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: Do you have a MySQL server running?

Comment: @Galironfydar I have previously worked in a django project there I didnt do anything like this so i thought i dont need to start MySQL server running ? What are the steps for running MySQL server

Comment: Okay, seems like you don't have a MySQL server installed. You can follow this guide on [Installing MySQL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04) within WSL. Once you've configured it, it should be a case of using the correct connection details.

Comment: @Galironfydar Thanks for your reply it helped me a lot .I faced a few more errors but I did solve it. Mentioned article was specific to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ,but there were some issues with wsl2 ,but it helped me.